# How to do a CSS table

Tags: html, css, seo

I want to know how to do a css table with DIVS and to make the rows even/odd with diferent colors. the data columns must to be static or  go with the content if this exceed the space on one row.

the rows are autogenerated by a for in php who get data out from a db.  The HTML table is not suitable because is not SEO friendlly. data from this table is very important and i want it to get indexed very well.

i also wanna know how to do a pop up with a captcha when a page is displayed  like those javascript alerts and if this kind of practice is good for SEO and indexing content

Thanks

table code for picture  http://i46.tinypic.com/et8vuv.jpg

```
  if (count($results1))
 {   echo "CURSURI:";
      echo "<div id='curs'><ul>";
  echo "<li><ui>Nume</ui><ui> Uploader</ui><ui>Tip</ui><ui>Data</ui> </li>";
foreach($results1 as $x) {
 echo "<li><ui>". $i++.". <a href='".$x->link."'>". $x->name. "</a></ui>       <ui>".$x->user."</ui><ui>".$x->ext."</ui><ui>".$x->date."</ui> </li>";}
echo "</ul></div>";
}
```

Comment: If your data is tabular, use a table. There's nothing wrong with using a `<table>` tag for its intended purpose.

Comment: `The HTML table is not suitable because is not SEO friendly`, this is a bit of a generalisation. A table misappropiated for layout purposes is not SEO friendly. Other than that, need some code to see how to help you.

Comment: **The HTML table is not suitable because is not SEO friendly** that's simply not true

Comment: A Google search for "CSS table" returns **a lot** of results...

Comment: The last bit about pop-ups should be asked in a separate question.

Comment: If you want to arrange *non-tabular* data in a grid, you can use `table`, `table-row` etc display properties (IE8+ only) - e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ZR2gt/... obviously this example *is* tabular data, so it'd be daft to do this rather than just using a table, but it shows the principle.

Answer (score 2):

A table is an html construct--not CSS. You can use CSS to make a display LOOK like a table, but if you want it to look like a table, odds are that it's tabular data and, as such, you are much better off using an actual HTML table for accessibility and usability reasons.

I'm not sure why you believe a table wouldn't be SEO friendly.

Comment: http://i46.tinypic.com/et8vuv.jpg this is how it looks and  i edit the code

Comment: my data are links and cells are describing the files behind the links